# how to integrate UCD in jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, udeploy, ucd

I am trying to integrate IBM Urban Code Deploy in my Jenkins pipeline. Earlier I have integrated UCD using freestyle job using IBM UrbanCode Deploy Plugin. Now When I am trying to do the same using pipeline script, it is giving error. Unable to find many resources on the internet. Here is my Deploy stage.

```
stage('Deploy') {
        steps {
            UCDeployPublisher (
                siteName: 'udeploy-server',
                component: [
                    componentName: 'DemoApp-APP',
                    delivery: [
                        pushVersion: '${BUILD_NUMBER}',
                        baseDir: '${WORKSPACE}',
                        fileIncludePatterns: '**/*',
                        fileExcludePatterns: '',
                        pushDescription: 'Pushed from Jenkins',
                        pushIncremental: false
                    ]
                ],
                deploy: [
                    deployApp: 'DemoApp',
                    deployEnv: 'Test 1',
                    deployProc: 'DemoApp Process'
                ]
              )
        }
    }
```

I am getting the following error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'UCDeployPublisher' found among steps
```

Comment: Have you tried using it like in these examples, https://github.com/UrbanCode/jenkins-pipeline-ucd-plugin

Comment: tried to use from the example got an error.    
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: no known implementation of interface jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep is named UCDeployPublisher

Comment: I do notice the documentation only shows scripted pipeline examples and no declarative examples, which may be the issue here.

Comment: yes, I tried to convert it in declarative but maybe I am wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UCDeployPublisher` is a class, not a step. According to [the docs](https://www.urbancode.com/resource/jenkins-build-step-integration-with-ibm-urbancode-deploy/) you can use it with general [`step`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#step-general-build-step):

```groovy
stage('Deploy') {
    steps {
        step([$class: 'UCDeployPublisher',
            siteName: 'udeploy-server',
            // ... and so on
        ])           
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried the same but still getting error - `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: no known implementation of interface jenkins.tasks.SimpleBuildStep is named UCDeployPublisher`

Comment: @ShivanshKumar Are plugin and its dependencies correctly installed?

Comment: Yes, as I have integrated UCD using freestyle job using IBM UrbanCode Deploy Plugin, and it is working fine.

Comment: @ShivanshKumar Try this: `$class: 'com.urbancode.jenkins.plugins.ucdeploy.UCDeployPublisher'`

Comment: `$class: 'UCDeployPublisher'` works. Actually, for the freestyle project, I used the plugin `IBM UrbanCode Deploy Plugin` but for pipeline job the plugin needed was `IBM UrbanCode Deploy Pipeline (Build Steps) Plugin`. After installing and configuring this plugin the build was successful and was able to deploy.